# Finding top 10 occurrences in data

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql

I am trying to find the top 10 mentions (@xxxxx) in my twitter data. I have  created the initial table  twitter.full_text_ts and loaded it with my data.

```
create table twitter.full_text_ts as
select id, cast(concat(substr(ts,1,10), ' ', substr(ts,12,8)) as timestamp) as  ts, lat, lon, tweet
from full_text;
```

Ive been able to extract the mentions in the tweets by using this query (patterns)

```
select id, ts, regexp_extract(lower(tweet), '(.*)@user_(\\S{8})([:| ])(.*)',2) as patterns
from twitter.full_text_ts
order by patterns desc
limit 50;
```

executing this gives me

```
USER_a3ed4b5a   2010-03-07 03:46:23 fffed220
USER_dc8cfa6f   2010-03-05 18:28:39 fffdabf9
USER_dc8cfa6f   2010-03-05 18:32:55 fffdabf9
USER_915e3f8c   2010-03-07 03:39:09 fffdabf9
and so on...
```

You can see the fffed220 etc is the extracted patterns.

Now what I would like to do is count the number of times each of these mentions (patterns) occurs and output the top 10. for example fffdabf9 occurs 20 times, fffxxxx occurs 17 times and so on.

Comment: Hive won't let me use count with the regex_extract()patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most readable way to do this would be to save your first query into a temporary table, then do a groupby on the temp table:

```
create table tmp as
--your query

select patterns, count(*) n_mentions
from tmp
group by patterns
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: it won't let me group by patterns cause its not a column

Comment: got it to work by querying the temp table with select patterns, count(*) as cnt 
    > from tmp1
    > group by patterns
    > order by cnt desc
    > limit 10;

Answer (score 0):

```
with mentions as 
(select id, ts, 
 regexp_extract(lower(tweet), '(.*)@user_(\\S{8})([:| ])(.*)',2) as patterns
from twitter.full_text_ts
order by patterns desc
limit 50)
select patterns, count(*) 
from mentions
group by patterns
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```